# How can I use a texture as a font in Unity3D

Tags: unity, textures, fonts

I am making a game in unity and I am trying to make a custom font for showing numbers. I created a png with the numbers, turned it into a material and added it to a custom font object. I set up the index so that it knows where the number are. I set it to a style and used the style with a label to print some numbers to the screen. The numbers printed but the detail from the texture disappeared and the numbers became a single color determined by the text color setting in the style. Is there a way for the text to just show the graphics from the texture.

The alpha is working but the non alpha parts are all set to the same color. I have multiple colors in the text but on the screen they just appear as one color. Also when I add the material to a plain it all shows up properly so I am assuming that it has something to do with the font settings or the style settings.

here's a screeshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bxhs.jpg

Comment: can you show some screenshots of the issue?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/rqAhd